# Is NVDECODE API support H.265 mpegts

Tags: decoder, mpeg2-ts, h.265

I tried to use NVDECODE API to decode H.265 mpeg-ts video and met some problem. The video is freeze but works well with CPU decoder. I also tried NVDECODE API on H.265 mp4 video, it works well.
I traced the code and found the output from cuvid parser may have some problems to make error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n0gV.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YpCl.png)
As you can see, the PicWidthInMbs and FrameHeightInMbs are 0, which is not normal. Any suggestion to resolve it? Or it was a bug from Nvidia?

Comment: Perhaps your code is incorrect, perhaps NVidia bug, at choice. If you provide minimal source code which reproduces the problem, perhaps we can help.

Comment: The sample source can download from here: https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk#Download 
download Video Codec SDK 8.2.
And create a H265 mpeg2-ts for AppDec, you will see "NvDecoder::HandlePictureDecode : cuvidDecodePicture(m_hDecoder, pPicParams) returned error 1 at d:\video_codec_sdk_8.2.15\samples\nvcodec\nvdecoder\nvdecoder.cpp:432"

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from NVidia CUVID Parser documentation, but i think that this parser doesn't have enough information from ts file.

when i see the second image, it seems that some parsing have been done : BitStreamDataLen, ref_pic_flag, intra_pic_flag, etc... seem to be initialized.

Perhaps, you just need to give to the parser VPS/SPS/PPS data manually, because it seems they are missing with this ts file, or not well parse.

From h265 spec, it seems that the video size comes from SPS data : pic_width_in_luma_samples/pic_height_in_luma_samples.

I will try with h264 ts to get an idea (because i don't have NVidia GPU h265 compliant).